# ng-bootstrap Pagination hiding/removing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I Am implementing pagination on my project using the ng-bootstrap pagination, I have an ngFor on my HTML together with the **slice pipe** for filtering elements to display.

`<tr *ngFor="let bankAccount of bankingAccounts | slice: (page - 1) * pageSize:(page - 1) * pageSize + pageSize;let i = index;">`

All is working well, but the problem is that the Slice pipe completely removes the elements from the DOM while I still need to reference those removed elements from my typeScript.

Is the another pipe or method which I can use to paginate that will not remove my elements from the DOM while handling this pagination. Thanks..

Comment: Why would you need to keep them in DOM? It will slow down browser

Comment: I need to keep it so that I can still reference it from my typescript even those its not visible on the DOM... for validation purposes

Comment: I'm sorry, but if some kind of validation requires element to be in DOM you might have flawed validation. If you want to hide elements use something like `[class.hide]="isHidden(i)"` - this is a BAD idea in many ways, but could get what you want.

Comment: @BojanKogoj, use [class.hide] it's a bad idea because the class hide can conflic with another class -e.g. y you're using display:flex, but you can can use [style.display]="!condition?'none':null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [style.display]="!condition?'none':null" some like (*)

```html
    <ng-container *ngFor="let bankAccount of values;let i = index;">
      <tr [style.display]="i/pageSize>=page || i/pageSize<(page-1)?'none':null">
        ...
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

(*) in the code I use the way `[style.display]=condition?'none':null`

BTW: really I don't understand when you say you need to "validation". If you're using a FormArray, rememeber that the FormArray exist independently there are inputs or not, if you "validate" over the array, the array exist independently is showed all the array or only part